# Toolbar fica atras dos Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo uma tela de home, e tem 1 toolbar e 2 linearLayouts dividindo a tela em 2.
o problema é que o toolbar fica "atras" dos layouts e nao aparece quando executa. 
como trago o toolbar pra primeiro plano em cima dos linearlayout?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_main"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente coloque seu toolbar por último no layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_main"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo atributos do seu container LinearLayout, o pai dessas views é uma RelativeLayout, correto?!

RelativeLayout funciona diferente das outras views. Você precisa informar a hierarquia das views, por isso basta colocar no seu container LinearLayout o atributo **android:layout_below="@+id/tb_main"**, informando que ele deve ficar abaixo da toolbar.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/tb_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
```